# How to save my changes in XML file with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have the following simple XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user-mapping>

</user-mapping>
```

I want to add content to the user mapping using Nokogiri.

This is my code:

```
f = File.open("exam.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
puts doc.to_s
map = doc.at_css "user-mapping"
map.content = "Gholam"
puts map.to_s
doc.to_xml
f.close
```

The output of the `puts` are:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user-mapping>

</user-mapping>
<user-mapping>Gholam</user-mapping>
```

But when the code ends, nothing has been change in the actual XML file.
Can anyone explain to me how to save my changes in the XML file?

Comment: Write the file to disk using standard Ruby convention. There is no special feature in Nokogiri for writing files.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Read the file into an in-memory XML document, modify the document as needed, then serialize the document back into the original file:

```rb
filename = 'exam.xml'
xml = File.read(filename)
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
# ... make changes to doc ...
File.write(filename, doc)
```

Comment: Or `File.write(filename, doc.to_xml)`

Comment: `to_xml` is not needed, just `File.write(filename, doc)`